# Apache shows 404 error using mod_wsgi for my django application

Tags: python, django, apache

For my django application (called 'iwidget') I have created (and installed using `a2ensite`) this virtual host configuration file (`001-default`)

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/user/.virtualenvs/iwidget

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        WSGIDaemonProcess iwidget processes=4 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/home/user/.virtualenvs/iwidget/lib/python2.7
        WSGIProcessGroup iwidget

        WSGIScriptAlias /iwidget /home/user/iwidget/iwidget/wsgi.py
        Alias /iwidget/static/ /home/user/iwidget/iwidget/staticfiles/
<VirtualHost>
```

And this is my `wsgi.py` (in `/home/user/iwidget/iwidget/` directory.)

```
import os, sys, site                                                   

site.addsitedir('/home/user/.virtualenvs/iwidget/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/home/user/.virtualenvs/iwidget/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))                  

sys.path.append('/home/user/iwidget')                              
sys.path.append('/home/user/iwidget/iwidget')                      

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "iwidget.settings")   
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application                      
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

However, I am getting this error

```
[warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[error] File does not exist: /var/www/iwidget
```

`/var/www/iwidget`? Why is Apache looking in this directory? What am I doing wrong?

Note. There is already a `default` vhost configuration pointing which is working fine. This is my second (that is why I called it `001-default`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two configuration files, but no way of distinguishing between them. Apache will simply match everything against the original one, since it's first alphabetically, and never get to the new one - hence why it is looking in /var/www, since that's evidently the DocumentRoot set in 001-default.

Do you actually need this to be in a separate file? There's no reason you couldn't add this configuration inside 001-default. Otherwise, you will need to have them on separate ports, or use a ServerName directive to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to have them both in the same `default` file, but unfortunately `WSGIPythonhome` directive cannot be inside the `VirtualHost` tag and so I had to remove the second configuration and add it in a separate vhost file. So, I guess I can't avoid using two `default` files. How can I use the `ServerName` directive? Can you update your answer?

Comment: Well, as I think I've told you before, the fact that you need the WSGIPythonHome directive at all seems wrong. Normally you manage all of that via a virtualenv which you activate in your wsgi file. A ServerName will only work if you access the different configurations via different host names.

Comment: I changed the port from 80 to 8080 and now it works. Thanks!